# Storage devices suddenly classified as Unspecified, Category:Other and USB memory sticks have Unspecified icon (Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows-8.1, icons, storage

After a recent reboot, Windows 8.1 has done something peculiar to my storage devices. In the Devices and Printers window, they have all been moved to the classification of "Unspecified" and are only listed as "Device" with a very generic box icon. That same icon appears for my flash drives (not the regular drives) in the This Computer window, overriding both the normal generic windows icon and icons set by the autorun configuration file. I have rebooted, unplugged and replugged in the USB devices and tried to get Windows Update to update the drivers, which it says they are already the latest, I have reformatted one flash drive and I have deleted and rebuilt my icon cache.

Worth noting that I can access and use all of the devices just fine but this is still unexpected and abnormal behavior that I would like to know the cause of and get fixed.

[My drives, with flash drive (X) showing the wrong icon.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5jhO.png)

[The icon the flash drive (X) used to have.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6eRL.png)

[Devices and Printers showing all of my storage devices as unspecified devices (ignore the warning sign on two of the devices, it is an unrelated issue and is just bad timing of my taking the screen shot.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCYIJ.png)

EDIT: Per comment below, it would appear at least 4 other people are having this problem today or at the very least, very recently.

Answer (score 0):

Huh.. This just happened to me today. In "Devices and Printer" both my SSD and USB drive show as unspecified and the icon of the flash drive in "This PC" changed just like yours.

I also found these 2 threads with the same issue, both were created today by the same person:

https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/144163-all-usb-drives-external-shows-device-icon-like-unspecified.html

https://www.windowsphoneinfo.com/threads/all-usb-drives-external-shows-device-icon-like-unspecified.259054/

These sudden unexplained changes makes me nervous. Please post here if you find the cause. I will too. Sorry about posting this as an answer, can't make a comment.

Edit: Forgot to mention, I'm using Windows 10. Windows Update is currently paused so the issue is likely not because of a Windows update.

Comment: Well, that's concerning.

Comment: I just found another thread in tenforums full of people with this problem, including Windows 8.1 and Windows 10. https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/143991-usb-drives-displaying-weird-icons-i-believe-usb-3-0-ports-only-2.html

Comment: Oh. Very recent as well. I've been googling for a bit and couldn't find that exact issue with any old threads. There are similar issues, but not this exact one. This looks like a very recent problem, which affected multiple users and was likely not caused by an official windows update. Not sure how to feel about this.

Comment: Found a reddit thread with a probable cause mentioned in the comments. https://old.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/dt34zw/the_icon_that_displays_in_explorer_for_flash/

Comment: Do you have any new folders in %PROGRAMDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\DeviceMetadataCache\ ? I have one from yesterday and within that folder's DeviceInformation, contains our good friend ico2001.ico. 

I don't know enough to read into what exactly this is all doing but going to give a try to deleting and rebooting without internet connected.

Comment: Yes, I do have 2 new folders in \DeviceMetadataCache\dmrccache\en-US\. Both were created yesterday and one of them has ico2001.ico inside its DeviceInformation. I'm a bit relieved that it's nothing malicious but I don't know what exactly is Microsoft trying to do here.

Comment: The fact that they can just mess up anyone's PC at any time with no way for me to stop it. I have all the privacy settings turned off and the updates paused because of that exact reason yet they still refuse keep their hands out of my system *sigh*.

Comment: Deleting the cache didn't fix it, so it must require something a little more thorough. That said, I am 99% confident that this is what it is. You can disable automatic meta data downloading for devices in Windows 8.1. I think you can do it in 10 if you have access to the group policy editor. It's all separate from the regular update stuff is my point (because, of course it is.). Now to figure out how to revert.

Comment: I do notice svchost.exe drawing some bandwidth every now and then. Investigating these connections always reveals that they are done by a Windows component or service so they definitely still download some stuff even when updates are paused. Well, at least we're not as worried anymore. Since it's nothing serious and the affected devices still work as intended, I'd probably wait a couple more days, maybe they'd fix it from their end. Thank you very much for sharing your findings.

Comment: By disabling meta data, deleting the dmrccache AND deleting my icon cache, I was able to get the icons to appear as the empty file icon. Still can't revert to the original icons and the non-icon data that puts it in the "Other" category still needs fixed. I'm hoping Microsoft didn't fubar things in a way that won't allow easy reverting.